# My text is cut off, how can I solve that?

Tags: html, css

I am doing a website and my text is cut off at the bottom of my page. I can fix the margins and make my picture and text small enough to fit the page, but I would rather make it so I can scroll down in my web page. How would I go by doing that?

[Here](https://codepen.io/joshfer2000/pen/gmpVpN) is the link to my web page in order to clear up any confusion (don't mind the content of the page, I'm testing a few things).

Comment: A working link: http://codepen.io/joshfer2000/pen/gmpVpN

Comment: I tried to add the real link http://codepen.io/joshfer2000/pen/gmpVpN to your question, but it wouldn't let me since you posted no code, and links without code are not accepted by SO

Answer (score 2):

Your  `<nav>` tag doesn't have a closing tag, so the browser interprets it as if the *whole* content (*everything* between `<body>` and `</body>`) were inside the `<nav>` tag, which has fixed position and therefore can't scroll...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you css:

```
overflow: scroll;
```